# Limiting the number of characters in mysql tables

Tags: mysql, database, sql-types

Is it useful to limit the number of digits as `int(5)` when creating a MySQL table? I think `int(5)` and `int(11)` are almost the same and use 4 bytes of storage. Similar case of `varchar(50)` and `varchar(255)`. Am I right? Or it has benefit to limit the number of characters (digits) when creating a table?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`int(5)` and `int(11)` are stored in the same way, the number is just a representational option called "display width". It may be used by some applications to pad the field when displaying it.

With `varchar`, the number indicates an upper limit of the length of the string that may be stored. Since `varchar` fields are of a variable size, the actual used bytes may be equal to or less than that. This limit may even be used as a rudimentary form of validation.

Answer (score 0):

> The int size is neither bits nor bytes. It's just the display width, that is used when the field has ZEROFILL specified.

This [blog](http://alexander.kirk.at/2007/08/24/what-does-size-in-intsize-of-mysql-mean/) explains the meaning of int(size) in MySQL.